# A more pythonic (or vectorised) function to drop slices of an array that are all nan

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization

I have a 4D array, of which 3D 'slices' in the first dimension are sometimes all nans. I'm looking for a pythonic way to prune these. Currently I'm using a for loop and iterating through the slices:

```
def drop_nan_rows(tracks_array):
    
    """A function that finds 'slices' of all-nans along the first dim of a numpy array and deletes them."""
    
    indices_to_drop = []

    for index in range(tracks_array.shape[0]):
        if np.isnan(tracks_array[index]).all():
            indices_to_drop.append(index)
            
    print(indices_to_drop)
    
    tracks_array = np.delete(tracks_array, indices_to_drop, axis=0)

    return(tracks_array)
```

To test this function you can use:

```
# Define a 4D numpy array and fill with ones

W = 365; X = 361; Y=361; Z=3

a = np.ones([W,X,Y,Z])

#Make a 'slice' of nans on the seventh and eleventh 'rows'

nans = np.full((X,Y,Z),np.nan)
a[7,:,:,:] = nans
a[11,:,:,:] = nans

# Now detect the slices of nans and remove them

print(a.shape)

a = drop_nan_rows(tracks_array)

print(a.shape)
```

The for loop isn't very pythonic, and I'd like to do something like this (which works for a 2d array):

```
tracks_array = tracks_array[~np.isnan(tracks_array).any(axis=1)]
```

But for some reason I can't get this to work on arrays in 3 and 4 dimensions?

Comment: You can pass `axis=(1, 2, 3)` to `any` in your last snippet to make it work with your 4D array.

Comment: Thank you, that's the right answer! 

I was previously trying axis=1, or axis=2 etc but didn't realise you could pass a tuple.

Cheers